# Decrease values by 1 in a table column with a header (bash)

Tags: bash

I have a large table like this

```
chr hg19_pos hg19_pos ref alt REVEL Ensembl_transcriptid
1 35142 35142 G A 0.027 ENST00000417324
1 35142 35142 G C 0.035 ENST00000417324
1 35142 35142 G T 0.043 ENST00000417324
1 35143 35143 T A 0.018 ENST00000417324
1 35143 35143 T C 0.034 ENST00000417324
1 35143 35143 T G 0.039 ENST00000417324
1 35144 35144 A C 0.012 ENST00000417324
1 35145 35145 C A 0.023 ENST00000417324
1 35145 35145 C G 0.029 ENST00000417324
```

and I need this

```
chr hg19_pos hg19_pos ref alt REVEL Ensembl_transcriptid
1 35141 35142 G A 0.027 ENST00000417324
1 35141 35142 G C 0.035 ENST00000417324
1 35141 35142 G T 0.043 ENST00000417324
1 35142 35143 T A 0.018 ENST00000417324
1 35142 35143 T C 0.034 ENST00000417324
1 35142 35143 T G 0.039 ENST00000417324
1 35143 35144 A C 0.012 ENST00000417324
1 35144 35145 C A 0.023 ENST00000417324
1 35144 35145 C G 0.029 ENST00000417324
```

I have tried this

```
awk '{ $2-=1; print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8 }' revel_with_transcript_ids.bed | head

chr -1 hg19_pos ref alt REVEL Ensembl_transcriptid
1 35141 35142 G A 0.027 ENST00000417324
1 35141 35142 G C 0.035 ENST00000417324
1 35141 35142 G T 0.043 ENST00000417324
1 35142 35143 T A 0.018 ENST00000417324
1 35142 35143 T C 0.034 ENST00000417324
1 35142 35143 T G 0.039 ENST00000417324
1 35143 35144 A C 0.012 ENST00000417324
1 35144 35145 C A 0.023 ENST00000417324
1 35144 35145 C G 0.029 ENST00000417324
```

Comment: Since you want to output all fields, a lone `print` would be enough. However in your code, the operation also occurs in the header line, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```bash
awk 'NR > 1 {$2 -= 1} 1' file

chr hg19_pos hg19_pos ref alt REVEL Ensembl_transcriptid
1 35141 35142 G A 0.027 ENST00000417324
1 35141 35142 G C 0.035 ENST00000417324
1 35141 35142 G T 0.043 ENST00000417324
1 35142 35143 T A 0.018 ENST00000417324
1 35142 35143 T C 0.034 ENST00000417324
1 35142 35143 T G 0.039 ENST00000417324
1 35143 35144 A C 0.012 ENST00000417324
1 35144 35145 C A 0.023 ENST00000417324
1 35144 35145 C G 0.029 ENST00000417324
```

Comment: `NR > 1` makes sure to only execute action block for record number `>1` (starting from 2nd row)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 
   'chr hg19_pos hg19_pos ref alt REVEL Ensembl_transcriptid
    1 35142 35142 G A 0.027 ENST00000417324
    1 35142 35142 G C 0.035 ENST00000417324
    1 35142 35142 G T 0.043 ENST00000417324
    1 35143 35143 T A 0.018 ENST00000417324
    1 35143 35143 T C 0.034 ENST00000417324
    1 35143 35143 T G 0.039 ENST00000417324
    1 35144 35144 A C 0.012 ENST00000417324
    1 35145 35145 C A 0.023 ENST00000417324
    1 35145 35145 C G 0.029 ENST00000417324' |
```

---

```
mawk '!_++ || --$2'
```

---

```
chr hg19_pos hg19_pos ref alt REVEL Ensembl_transcriptid
1 35141 35142 G A 0.027 ENST00000417324
1 35141 35142 G C 0.035 ENST00000417324
1 35141 35142 G T 0.043 ENST00000417324
1 35142 35143 T A 0.018 ENST00000417324
1 35142 35143 T C 0.034 ENST00000417324
1 35142 35143 T G 0.039 ENST00000417324
1 35143 35144 A C 0.012 ENST00000417324
1 35144 35145 C A 0.023 ENST00000417324
1 35144 35145 C G 0.029 ENST00000417324
```